# Does anyone know of a Go Lang websocket client that is compatible with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket, go

I want to stream data to a backend from a server that uses websockets i.e. I would like the backend to behave like a websocket client.

I tried the [websocket package](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket) but that uses a whole load of App Engine non-whitelisted functions.

Answer (score 2):

AppEngine does not currently support WebSockets. The closest equivalent is the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/channel/), but that is still more limited than WebSockets.

Edit: The new experimental Sockets API is even closer than the Channel API, but still doesn't allow listening sockets, which is a core requirement to implement WebSockets.

Comment: I am not sure this is still true with the new [Sockets API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) for Go Java and Python. Surely a WebSockets implementation just needs to be implemented on top of the Sockets API?

Comment: @Dan There's still a critical limitation there: *"You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets."* Browsers never listen - they connect to a server-side socket to initiate the connection. If the server isn't allowed to listen, then you can't set up WebSockets.

Comment: I agree with you however I want to stream data _to_ the backend i.e. I want the backend to act as a websocket client, not server. I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The new VM-Based backends are a good fit for this kind of scenario. They allow you to run non-whitelisted code on Compute Engine virtual machines as part of your App Engine application. The program is currently in Early Access, see this post for information on signing up: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys/BbOHxcgYt2IJ